# Bypass UAC complete in W8 or W8.1

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, permissions, uac, visual-studio-2013

In my school, we have low-level user accounts (obviously) so we can do everything we want, except changing important stuff etc.

However, the PC which was assigned to me has been having some issues, namely Visual Studio not functioning anymore (it literally crashes 2 sec after hitting the shortcut). After doing some research I found that an repair + update are needed to fix it.

So I told my teacher (so he could tell the network admin) & he assigned me a different PC, which ALSO has issues. This new (2nd) PC, Visual Studio works, to an extent...

I can do just about anything in there, except for what may just be Visual Studio's most important & useful function, which is debugging. Everytime I try to debug my code it gives me an error:

Unable to start project: Invalid pointer.

All I can do right now, is launch my projects without the debugger & hope that it works, because if it doesn't, I won't get any information as to why it won't work.

Again after doing some research, a simple repair/update should do the trick.

Here's where my real problem lies; as I don't have permissions to make any changes to the PC (not permitted by UAC) and my teacher doesn't have the necessary rights on his account either, I'm stuck with 2 PC's with a VS install that's broken.

So my question:

How can I run the Visual Studio installer without having UAC request a password from me?

OR

If you happen to know how to fix it without using UAC, please share.

Note: I tried Task Scheduler, however UAC (again) won't allow me to create new tasks. I tried making one with elevated permissions & it simply didn't work...

Comment: You don't need administrator rights to do what your doing, so these problems, are not caused by having only User permissons

Comment: Take the second one back to your teacher. I'm pretty sure once he sees it happening in more than one device he'll escalate it up to the school's IT staff. If he (only) offers you another device, tell him you want to see it working as you need it, before you leave. :)

Comment: @Ramhound actually I do, as VS is installed in Program Files, where  the repair tool is trying to make changes. & Techie007, I already have, all he could do was tell the net admin about it, which he did... 2-3 months ago

Comment: I meant you don't need it to debug your project...the actual problem with the installtion can't be solved without Administrator permissions.

Comment: Oh... I thought you meant I didn't need admin rights to repair the installation, however I know I don't need admin rights to actually run VS, that'd be pretty stupid. But why bring it up? I know the debugging not working isn't a permission issue, but that's not what I'm asking either.

Answer (score 1):

Someone is responsible for the computers and has the passwords, and can fix your problem. Figure out who that person is, and they are likely to help you fix the issue. Contact that person directly, in person. Your teacher is obviously not that person.

Visual Studio is likely installed in program files, which is protected by default and therefore requires elevated privileges to modify files there.

There are various ways to elevate privileges of an account other than UAC, but these are security vulnerabilities, which are occasionally fixed. Also I don't think superuser is the right place to ask for these.

Comment: Unfortunately, my teacher has already forwarded the issue with both PC's in great detail to the net admin, but that was about 2-3 months ago & still no change :( Also, I just got told this would most likely be the place to ask this, so if you have a better alternative, feel free to ask.

Comment: @Yorrick Just grab the net admin yourself instead of relying on a response to an email someone else sent 2-3 months ago. Knock on the door to their office, in person - no email. Running an installer to repair VS requires elevated privileges. Elevated privileges are something handed out by an administrator. Granting yourself elevated privileges using a vulnerability is your other option, but that could be illegal in some countries so no one here will tell you how to do that.

Comment: I tried, but I can't find any contact details, all I have is a name & he's barely ever there, only when called, so talking to him personally is pretty much impossible. Also, I can't find any rule explicitly prohibiting "_illegal_" things from being advised here, so why would no one here tell me? Are the people here really such posers? Because if you're telling me no one here has ever done/tried something illegal, be it with PC's or not, is utterly ridiculous